# Pandas dataframe change values in a column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, panel-data

I have a large Dataframe below:

The data used as the example here 'education_val.csv' can be found here https://github.com/ENLK/Py-Projects-/blob/master/education_val.csv

```
import pandas as pd 

edu = pd.read_csv('education_val.csv')
del edu['Unnamed: 0']
edu.head(10)

ID  Year    Education
22445   1991    higher education
29925   1991    No qualifications
76165   1991    No qualifications
223725  1991    Other
280165  1991    intermediate qualifications
333205  1991    No qualifications
387605  1991    higher education
541285  1991    No qualifications
541965  1991    No qualifications
599765  1991    No qualifications
```

The values in the column `Education` are:

```
edu.Education.value_counts()

intermediate qualifications 153705
higher education    67020
No qualifications   55842
Other   36915
```

I want to replace the values in the column Education in the following ways:

1. If an `ID` has the value `higher education` in a year in the column `Education` then all future years for that `ID` will also have `higher education` in the `Education` column.
2. If an `ID` has the value `intermediate qualifications` in a year, then all future years for that `ID` will have `intermediate qualifications` in the corresponding `Education` column. However, if the value `higher education` occurs in any of the subsequent years for this `ID`, then `higher education` replaces `intermediate qualifications` in the subsequent years, regardless if `Other` or `No qualifications occur`.

For example in the DataFrame below, `ID` 22445 has  the value`higher education` in the year `1991`, all subsequent values of `Education` for `22445` should be replaced with `higher education` in the later years, up to the year `2017`.

```
edu.loc[edu['ID'] == 22445]

ID  Year    Education
22445   1991    higher education
22445   1992    higher education
22445   1993    higher education
22445   1994    higher education
22445   1995    higher education
22445   1996    intermediate qualifications
22445   1997    intermediate qualifications
22445   1998    Other
22445   1999    No qualifications
22445   2000    intermediate qualifications
22445   2001    intermediate qualifications
22445   2002    intermediate qualifications
22445   2003    intermediate qualifications
22445   2004    intermediate qualifications
22445   2005    intermediate qualifications
22445   2006    intermediate qualifications
22445   2007    intermediate qualifications
22445   2008    intermediate qualifications
22445   2010    intermediate qualifications
22445   2011    intermediate qualifications
22445   2012    intermediate qualifications
22445   2013    intermediate qualifications
22445   2014    intermediate qualifications
22445   2015    intermediate qualifications
22445   2016    intermediate qualifications
22445   2017    intermediate qualifications
```

Similarly, `ID` 1587125 in the Dataframe below has the value `intermediate qualifications` in the year `1991`, and changes to `higher education` in `1993`. All subsequent values in the column `Education` in the future years (from 1993 onwards) for `1587125` should be `higher education`.

```
edu.loc[edu['ID'] == 1587125]

ID  Year    Education
1587125 1991    intermediate qualifications
1587125 1992    intermediate qualifications
1587125 1993    higher education
1587125 1994    higher education
1587125 1995    higher education
1587125 1996    higher education
1587125 1997    higher education
1587125 1998    higher education
1587125 1999    higher education
1587125 2000    higher education
1587125 2001    higher education
1587125 2002    higher education
1587125 2003    higher education
1587125 2004    Other
1587125 2005    No qualifications
1587125 2006    intermediate qualifications
1587125 2007    intermediate qualifications
1587125 2008    intermediate qualifications
1587125 2010    intermediate qualifications
1587125 2011    higher education
1587125 2012    higher education
1587125 2013    higher education
1587125 2014    higher education
1587125 2015    higher education
1587125 2016    higher education
1587125 2017    higher education
```

There are 12,057 unique `ID` in the data and the column `Year` spans from 1991 to 2017. How does one change the values of `Education` for all 12, 057 according to the above conditions? I'm not sure how to do this in a uniform way for all unique `ID`s. The sample data used as the example here is attached in the Github link above. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-data) like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ENLK/Py-Projects-/master/education_val.csv')

eddtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['No qualifications', 
                               'Other',
                               'intermediate qualifications',
                               'higher education'], 
                               ordered=True)
df['EducationCat'] = df['Education'].str.strip().astype(eddtype)

df['EduMax'] = df.sort_values('Year').groupby('ID')['EducationCat']\
                 .transform(lambda x: eddtype.categories[x.cat.codes.cummax()] )
```

It is broken it up explicitly so you can see the data manipulations I am using.

1. Create a Education [categorical dtype with order](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categoricaldtype)
2. Next, change dtype of Education column to use that categorical
   dtype (EducationCat)
3. Use the codes of the categorical to preform cummax calculation
4. With indexing to return the category defined by the cummax calculation (EduMax)

Outputs:

```
df[df['ID'] == 1587125]

            ID  Year                    Education                 EducationCat                       EduMax
18      1587125  1991  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications
12075   1587125  1992  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications
24132   1587125  1993             higher education             higher education             higher education
36189   1587125  1994             higher education             higher education             higher education
48246   1587125  1995             higher education             higher education             higher education
60303   1587125  1996             higher education             higher education             higher education
72360   1587125  1997             higher education             higher education             higher education
84417   1587125  1998             higher education             higher education             higher education
96474   1587125  1999             higher education             higher education             higher education
108531  1587125  2000             higher education             higher education             higher education
120588  1587125  2001             higher education             higher education             higher education
132645  1587125  2002             higher education             higher education             higher education
144702  1587125  2003             higher education             higher education             higher education
156759  1587125  2004                        Other                        Other             higher education
168816  1587125  2005            No qualifications            No qualifications             higher education
180873  1587125  2006  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications             higher education
192930  1587125  2007  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications             higher education
204987  1587125  2008  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications             higher education
217044  1587125  2010  intermediate qualifications  intermediate qualifications             higher education
229101  1587125  2011             higher education             higher education             higher education
241158  1587125  2012             higher education             higher education             higher education
253215  1587125  2013             higher education             higher education             higher education
265272  1587125  2014             higher education             higher education             higher education
277329  1587125  2015             higher education             higher education             higher education
289386  1587125  2016             higher education             higher education             higher education
301443  1587125  2017             higher education             higher education             higher education
```

Answer (score 2):

There clearly is an order in the level of education. Your problem can be restated as a "rolling max" problem: what is the highest level of education a person has as of a certain year?

Try this:

```
# A dictionary mapping each label to a rank
mappings = {e: i for i, e in enumerate(['No qualifications', 'Other', 'intermediate qualifications', 'higher education'])}

# Convert the label to its rank
edu['Education'] = edu['Education'].map(mappings)

# The gist of the solution: an expanding max level of education per person
tmp = edu.sort_values('Year').groupby('ID')['Education'].expanding().max()

# The first index level in tmp is the ID, the second level is the original index
# We only need the original index, hence the droplevel
# We also convert the rank back to the label (swapping keys and values in the mappings dictionary)
tmp = tmp.droplevel(0).map({v: k for k, v in mappings.items()})

edu['Education'] = tmp
```

Test:

```
edu[edu['ID'] == 1587125]

    ID  Year                    Education
1587125  1991  intermediate qualifications
1587125  1992  intermediate qualifications
1587125  1993             higher education
1587125  1994             higher education
1587125  1995             higher education
1587125  1996             higher education
1587125  1997             higher education
1587125  1998             higher education
1587125  1999             higher education
1587125  2000             higher education
1587125  2001             higher education
1587125  2002             higher education
1587125  2003             higher education
1587125  2004             higher education
1587125  2005             higher education
1587125  2006             higher education
1587125  2007             higher education
1587125  2008             higher education
1587125  2010             higher education
1587125  2011             higher education
1587125  2012             higher education
1587125  2013             higher education
1587125  2014             higher education
1587125  2015             higher education
1587125  2016             higher education
1587125  2017             higher education
```

Comment: I think yours is probably faster.  Might have to runs some timings to see.

Comment: Just run a quick, it was actually a tad slower than yours. The `lambda` inside transform was pretty cool. Didn't think of that

Comment: Thank you for running those timings and I appreciate the comment.  Just catering to my strengths of using the pandas library to its fullest.  Sometimes at the detriment to using numpy or native python methods. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the IDs, then through the years. The DataFrame is ordered chronologically, so if a person has 'higher education' or 'intermediate qualifications' in a cell, you can save this knowledge and apply it to subsequent cells:

```
edu = edu.set_index('ID')
ids = edu.index.unique()

for id in ids:
    # booleans to keep track of education statuses we've seen
    higher_ed = False
    inter_qual = False

    rows = edu.loc[id]
    for _, row in rows:
        # check for intermediate qualifications
        if inter_qual:
            row['Education'] = 'intermediate qualifications'
        elif row['Education'] = 'intermediate qualifications':
            inter_qual = True

        # check for higher education
        if higher_ed:
            row['Education'] = 'higher education'
        elif row['Education'] = 'higher education':
            higher_ed = True
```

It doesn't matter that we're potentially overwriting each status more than once — if a person has both 'intermediate qualifications' and 'higher education', we only need to be sure that 'higher education' is set last.

I would normally not suggest using a for loop to process a DataFrame — but each cell value might rely on values above it, and the Dataframe isn't so large as to make this infeasible.